# Почему обьект вызывающий метод передает в качестве аргумента поле другого обьекта а не свое

Tags: c#, ооп

```
class Unit
{
    protected int _health;
    protected int _damage;

    public virtual void Attack(Unit unit)
    {

        unit.TakeDamage(_damage);//почему скелет вызывая метод передает аргументом поле _damage обьекта Archer?.. а не свое поле
    }

    public virtual void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(damage);

        if (damage >= _health)
        {
            _health = 0;
            Die();
            return;
        }
        _health -= damage;
    }

    protected virtual void Die() { }
}

class Skeleton : Unit
{
    public Skeleton()
    {
        _health = 15;
        _damage = 12;
    }

    public override void Attack(Unit unit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Скелет атакует.");
        base.Attack(unit);
    }

    protected override void Die()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Скелет убит.");
    }
}

class Archer : Unit
{
    public Archer()
    {
        _health = 50;
        _damage = 15;
    }

    public override void Attack(Unit unit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Лучник атакует.");
        base.Attack(unit);
    }

    protected override void Die()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Лучник убит.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Archer archer = new Archer();
        Skeleton skelet = new Skeleton();
        archer.Attack(skelet);
        archer.Attack(skelet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему ты решил что скелет передаёт объект лучшника?

Comment: `unit.TakeDamage(_damage);` - тут unit будет `Skeleton`,  а `_damage` будет  то, что Лучник наносит другим.... что тут не так?

Comment: Я это знаю, я проследил отладчиком, просто не могу понять почему поле там будет _damage от лучника а не от обьекта скелет. Ещё после строки unit.TakeDamage(_damage) поля _health и _damage меняются с полей обьекта лучника на поля обьекта скелета и это тоже непонятно.

Comment: *"почему поле там будет _damage от лучника а не от обьекта скелет"* --- вызывается метод у какого объекта? У лучника. Поэтому у него и берётся значение

Comment: Дополню обьясню свой ход мыслей когда лучник атакует и доходит отладчик до строки public virtual void Attack(Unit unit)

Comment: *"поля _health и _damage меняются с полей обьекта лучника на поля обьекта скелета"* ---  у какого объека вызывается метод, того объекта данные и берутся. Это же основы программирования.... Если я пишу car.Drive() , то подставляются поля машины, а не дракона

Comment: Дополню, обьясню свой ход мыслей: когда лучник атакует и дальше от строки public virtual void Attack(Unit unit) обьект скелет переданный аргументом посредством параметра unit внутри этого метода вызывает метод TakeDamage() и поэтому я думаю что поле _damage должен быть передан от обьекта скелет в метод TakeDamage() так как он(скелет) вызывает TakeDamage().

Comment: *"так как он(скелет) вызывает TakeDamage()"* --- вызывает-то метод скелет, но происходит это внутри метода `Attack`, который был вызван лучником. А значит `_damage` в этом методе на тот момент принадлежит лучнику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И лучшник и скелет наследуются от `Unit`. И тот и другой имеют возможность вызвать методы `Attack` и `TakeDamage`.

В программировании (во всяком случае *C#*), если после наименования объета стоИт точка и имя метода, то метод вызвается у него и все свойства внутри этого метода, принадлежат этому объекту. Поэтому если написать `car.Drive()`, то свойства внутри метода будут от объекта `car`, а не ещё от какого-либо.

Если представить, что метод `Attack` не имеет паракметров, то при вызове `archer.Attack();` свойство `_damage` **всегда** принадлежит к лучнику и никак иначе. Если `skelet.Attack();`, от свойство `_damage` **всегда** принадлежит к скелету и никак иначе.  Аналогично с методом `TakeDamage`.

**Еще раз:**  передаёшь ли ты агрументы в методы или нет, то `_damage` принадлежит только тому объекту, на котором вызыван метод.

Однако в методе `Attack` можно передать любой объект, унаследованный от `Unit`.

и тогда на строчке `unit.TakeDamage` вызовется метод `TakeDamage` какого объекта? Правильно, того, что передали как аргумент..То есть можно считать, что если передали `skelet`, то будет на самом деле не `unit.TakeDamage`, а `skelet.TakeDamage`.  Если перередали как аргумент `archer`, то будет не `unit.TakeDamage`, `archer.TakeDamage`.

А что мы знаем о том, к чему применяется метод? Что свойства внутри метода будут от объекта, на котором вызвали метод. И получается, что если в качестве `unit` передали `skelet`, то это превращается в `skelet.TakeDamage(XXX)` и получается что у скелета начинает работать этот метод.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарии, разьяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит не от объекта, а от параметров метода.

В вашем случае создан класс Unit, от которого наследуются Skeleton и Arhcer.

```
 public override void Attack(Unit unit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Лучник атакует.");
    base.Attack(unit);
}
```

В этой части кода в параметрах указан Unit. Это значит что сюда можно ставить класс Unit, либо его классы наследники.